# Special chars to mysql after server change, UTF8?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, char, whm

We have recently changed from a shared hosting to a VPS, but I'm experiencing some problemns with inserting special chars into the database (examples: ö, Ú etc. ). My table is UTF8 and I don't believe I set it on the page. Was working just fine on the old server, but giving problems on the new. Is there some setting in WHM that changes the default charset?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The problem was that all my files were UTF-8 without BOM, and the file with the strange characters was just UTF-8. This did not seem to cause problems on the old server, but it did on the new.